# Where to put a Constants class that is accessible throughout my Grails app?

Tags: grails, constants

I have a simple question but the google and stackoverflow results didn't satisfy me at all.

How can I define a Constants class like:

```
public class Constants {
    public static final int SYSTEM_USER_ID = 1;
}
```

that can be called *everywhere* with **`Constants.SYSTEM_USER_ID`**

I tried it in `grails-app/utils` and `src/java` but for example I couldn't access inside a Service class.

Comment: FWIW, a "Constants class" is usually an anti-pattern. You should define the constants on a class that they're relevant to (in your case, perhaps the `User` class?), or treat them as configuration properties (see Don's answer below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put your Constants class into a package. Grails can't find the class if its not in a package itself.

Answer (score 16):

You might consider putting these constants into `Config.groovy` rather than a class. One advantage of this approach is that you can specify per-environment values for these constants. You can read the values of these using either the implicit `grailsApplication` variable or the `ConfigurationHolder` class.

Comment: I hope you [are joking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35989/how-can-you-detect-if-users-have-created-sock-puppet-accounts)! :-)

Comment: `ConfigurationHolder` is [deprecated](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ConfigurationHolder.html) and in Grails 3.0 the configuration file is `conf/application.yml`.